# Можно ли отправить письма в формате html?

Tags: java, android

В приложении имеется кнопка при нажатии на которую отправляется текст по указанному email, как можно отправить это сообщение так чтоб оно отобразилось в формате html?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068827/how-do-i-send-html-email-via-java пойдёт?

Comment: не совсем разобрался в этом, можете объяснить более подробно, тот код не сработал у меня

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение данной проблемы [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007540)

```
final Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:"));
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "The Subject");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(new StringBuilder()
.append("<p><b>Some Content</b></p>")
.append("<small><p>More content</p></small>")
.toString()));
```